# Is it possible to transfer a customer database from a .net site to a WordPress site? If so how does one go about it?

Tags: .net, wordpress, content-management-system

I have someone who has website with over 5,000 members (this is a commerce site) and all of their order history and info as well as sales tracking in their current site, which is .net and they are looking to upgrade to a newer site in WordPress. Just wondering if it is possible to transfer that info over or would she have to start from scratch?

Comment: the info isn't in the website; the info is in some kind of database. Can you migrate data from a database into a system? Sure! Will it automatically be a simple process that just works: nope. It *might* do, but in the real world you'll have a decent sized project to do to make that work

Comment: I knew it wasn't going to be simple. Do you have any ideas as to how this process is completed? or where I can find more information on this? Is this something that I can do myself (designer) or would I need a developer for this? I have no experience with asp.net, so don't know how complicated this would be.